# How would I get the event object giving this scenerio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using this plugin: http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/

And I am trying to get a hold of the event object when the onSelectALL method is called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#example-onSelectAll').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        onSelectAll: function() {
            alert('onSelectAll triggered!');
        }
    });
</script>
```

How would I pass it the event. I saw I can use windows.event in IE, but I am looking for a solution that will work in FF too. All I see is having a parameter to pass the event, but I don't have control over what is being passed.

I tried registering a click event to some of the elements called for the dropdown, but that did not work.

Edit, this is the code from my project. However it is using ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor to dynamically build the Html.

HTML:

```
             @if (item.IsSerialized)
             {
                 <select class="serialized" name="@item.PartName" multiple="multiple">
                   @foreach (SerialNumber sn in item.SerialNumbers)
                   {
                     <option value="@sn.SNSER">@sn.SNSER</option>
                   }
                 </select>
             }
```

Script:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.serialized').multiselect({
            onChange: test,
            onSelectAll: function () { console.log(this.$select); },
            buttonText: function (options, select) {
                return 'Choose';
            },
            buttonTitle: function (options, select) {
                var labels = [];
                options.each(function () {
                    labels.push($(this).text());
                });
                return labels.join(' - ');
            },
            inheritClass: true,
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `e` or `event` into the onSelectAll method arguments to see if it is passing it in?  Try `console.log(arguments)` to see what arguments are being given.

Comment: Have you tried just `onSelectAll: function(e){ console.log(e); }`?

Comment: Yes, I did try e and event in the method parameter, and it says undefined for both.

Comment: @Xufox "Undefined"

Comment: So `onSelectAll` doesn’t seem to have an Event associated with it. What kind of information are you trying to get?

Comment: in Chrome and IE you can just the the global 'event' object it seems FF and possibly Safari aren't going to be setting that. As @Xufox asked, what are you trying to do that you need the event for, maybe there is another way.

Comment: Well I am using multiple drop downs in a table, and I have a key associated with it stored at the select element level <select>. So if I get the object I can traverse up to get that key, to update other information on the page associated with the select all. In my case, I add or subtract the total selected to display to the user because the onChange passes the event. But when doing a select all, I need to be able to associate which dropdown box is being interacted with to change the total on a select all, where the onchange is not called.

Comment: @eaglei22 use this.$select in the function, that will get a reference to the original select.

Comment: @AdamH hmm, doing this: "var e = this.$select;"  I get e is undefined.

Comment: @eaglei22 Works fine for me. Replace `alert('onSelectAll triggered!');` by `console.log(this.$select)`. You’ll see a jQuery object that contains the original `<select>` element in the console.

Comment: @Xufox what browser are you using? I am using FireFox and I get undefined doing as you said:

              $(document).ready(function () {
                  $('.serialized').multiselect({
                      onChange: test,
                      onSelectAll: function () { console.log(this.$select) }...

Comment: @eaglei22 I’m using Firefox 63.0a1, testing with all the latest dependencies. As this `$select` isn’t browser specific, but specific to the plugin, I doubt this makes a difference. Can you [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] with the necessary HTML?

Comment: @Xufox, okay I edited my question to provide code from my project.

Comment: @eaglei22 What does `test` do? What does the rendered HTML look like? `this.$select` still doesn’t return `undefined` for me. What does just `this` look like at that point?